# how do I test the below code in jest which is related to error catching?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

when there is error while getting response from API requests this function helps in formatting the error.

```
export const getErrorMessage = (error) => {
  if (!error) {
    return DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE;
  }

  if (error instanceof Error && error.response && error.response.body && typeof error.response.body.error === "string") {
    return error.response.body.error;
  } else if (error instanceof Error && error.response && error.response.body  && typeof error.response.body.message === "string" ) {
    return error.response.body.message;
  } else if (error.message && typeof error.message === "string") {
    return error.message;
  }

  return DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE;
}
```

here DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE is some constant.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you want to simulate errors to use in your method. An Error is an object that you can create. You could do:

```
getErrorMessage(new Error)
```